# Ставится ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение типа: "Так что(,) я пойду один" - нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, хорошо бы увидеть предыдущее предложение. Если я заменю на "стало быть", "значит" - смысл не изменится? Тогда, вероятнее всего. это вводное слово (указывает на отношения между частями высказывания) и запятая ставится.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, нет. Разве только это вопрос.